# Gitlab CI - Add custom label/badge to pipeline after completing a certain stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

Is it possible to add a custom label/badge to a pipeline if a specific stage is successfully finished? This is how it normally looks:

[image]

As you can see the pipeline #1410 has the "latest" badge. I want to add a simular badge "last deploy" (maybe in another color) to pipeline #1409 when the latest stage successfully is finished. But only one pipeline can have this badge. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add custom badges. Gitlab is part open source, so theoretically you could build this yourself and try to get it merged.

Have a look at the `Environment` that Gitlab is providing https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#viewing-environments-and-deployments This is basically what you're looking for: Tracking which pipeline / commit hash is currently deployed.